# Should I flag reverted post after edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

I have edited some questions and answers to try to make them better. But why are my edits sometimes reverted?

Examples are [this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614001/how-to-upload-image-with-react-ckfinder-node-js/62234858#62234858) and [this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59959701/revisions). Should I edit again or should I report/flag it? Because sometimes, even if I edited it again, he/she reverted again.

Comment: As the duplicate says, you can explain to them how editing works here, and if they still roll it back again then you should flag it instead of starting a rollback war.

Comment: First rule - don't edit crap.  The 2nd answer is literally a copy and paste of the accepted answer.  It actually should be flagged and get deleted as it isn't an answer to the question.  IT is just an acknowledgement that the accepted answer worked

Comment: @psubsee2003 I edited from the late answer review, I have flagged answers like both answer but always rejected, so I never flagged post like that again.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur it all depends on what you flag and how.  You don't flag wrong answers, just downvote and move on.  But for something that is obviously what's wrong, you flag NAA (Not an Answer) or VLQ (Very Low Quality).  But for something more stuble like this one, you often need to use a custom flag to explain what is wrong.

Comment: @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur: Welcome to our editors guild! Don't be discouraged. It is natural to want to be "right", but at the first revert, it is better to leave a comment with an argument and maybe a source (e.g. "I think A, B, and C because of X, Y, and Z."). You can then choose to engage in comments or simply move on (to the next post). There is already plenty to tend to ([19,626,136 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) so far) and there is no need to hung on to any particular post.